# I cant write to database reference to show up in firebase console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

for some reason when I try to make a Databasereference it will not show up in my firebase console. I have a android app where I allow user to register/login and when they hit the register button a Databasereference should show up in the console with their userid as a child and they should be logged in. So the users are getting logged in but the Databasereference is writing to console. In the logs im getting a permission denied error. I set my rules to allow read and write so I dont know why that is happening and I made sure the google-services.json is correct for my app. Here is my code below

```
package com.example.movir;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class LendersLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lenders_login);

// ...
// Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final Button registerButton = findViewById(R.id.register_button);

        final ProgressBar loadingProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading);



        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LendersLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    String user_id= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Lenders").child(user_id);
                                    current_user_db.setValue(true);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LendersLoginActivity.this,LendersMenuPageActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(LendersLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    // ...
                                }


                                // ...
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LendersLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener< AuthResult >() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            String user_id= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Lenders").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LendersLoginActivity.this,LendersMenuPageActivity.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LendersLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });

    }
});



    }

}
```

Here are my logs

```
2021-03-14 11:24:05.511 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2021-03-14 11:24:05.583 14583-14614/com.example.movir W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-03-14 11:24:05.599 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: isEmailSend:POST
2021-03-14 11:24:05.656 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: port:443
2021-03-14 11:24:05.911 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: Check isMmsSendPdu
2021-03-14 11:24:05.921 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2021-03-14 11:24:06.224 14583-14614/com.example.movir W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-03-14 11:24:06.234 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: isEmailSend:POST
2021-03-14 11:24:06.242 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: Check isMmsSendPdu
2021-03-14 11:24:06.248 14583-14614/com.example.movir I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2021-03-14 11:24:06.418 14583-14614/com.example.movir D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 5mfvkS1vGndftKXzsE4yUkt4TMC2 ).
2021-03-14 11:24:06.418 14583-14614/com.example.movir D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 5mfvkS1vGndftKXzsE4yUkt4TMC2 ).
    
    --------- beginning of system
2021-03-14 11:24:06.488 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 28677
2021-03-14 11:24:06.505 14583-14711/com.example.movir V/FA: onActivityCreated
2021-03-14 11:24:06.517 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2021-03-14 11:24:06.525 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1162831406
2021-03-14 11:24:06.533 14583-14769/com.example.movir I/System.out: port:443
2021-03-14 11:24:06.585 14583-14588/com.example.movir I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=113KB
2021-03-14 11:24:06.587 14583-14588/com.example.movir I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=113KB
2021-03-14 11:24:06.587 14583-14588/com.example.movir I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2021-03-14 11:24:06.684 14583-14583/com.example.movir V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@2b33e7c[]
2021-03-14 11:24:06.687 14583-14583/com.example.movir D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@2b33e7c[LendersMenuPageActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@ed0972b
2021-03-14 11:24:06.691 14583-14583/com.example.movir D/ViewRootImpl[LendersMenuPageActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2021-03-14 11:24:06.692 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-14 11:24:06.697 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1162831603
2021-03-14 11:24:06.697 14583-14583/com.example.movir V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{42e658b com.example.movir/com.example.movir.LendersMenuPageActivity,ident = 3}, this = DecorView@2b33e7c[LendersMenuPageActivity]
2021-03-14 11:24:06.798 14583-14583/com.example.movir D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x982b7000)
2021-03-14 11:24:06.798 14583-14622/com.example.movir D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x982b7000,api=1)
2021-03-14 11:24:06.805 14583-14622/com.example.movir D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x982b7000,bufferCount=4)
2021-03-14 11:24:06.852 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-14 11:24:06.858 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-14 11:24:06.941 14583-14712/com.example.movir D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-03-14 11:24:06.946 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2021-03-14 11:24:06.957 14583-14622/com.example.movir E/[EGL-ERROR]: __egl_platform_cancel_buffers:644: surface->num_buffers(4)
2021-03-14 11:24:06.958 14583-14622/com.example.movir D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x981ff000,api=1)
2021-03-14 11:24:07.317 14583-14583/com.example.movir V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = ViewRoot{86bcf3f com.example.movir/com.example.movir.LendersLoginActivity,ident = 1}, this = DecorView@6c705e0[LendersLoginActivity]
2021-03-14 11:24:08.048 14583-14767/com.example.movir W/RepoOperation: setValue at /Users/Lenders/5mfvkS1vGndftKXzsE4yUkt4TMC2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2021-03-14 11:24:12.054 14583-14712/com.example.movir V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2021-03-14 11:24:12.061 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lg@bde9d9a
2021-03-14 11:24:12.063 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1494)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.065 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1655)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.067 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:712)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.068 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):0)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.070 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):2)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.071 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at lh.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):9)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.072 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at kr.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):3)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.074 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):3)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.075 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.076 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-03-14 11:24:12.077 14583-14712/com.example.movir W/System.err:     at im.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@210613128@21.06.13 (110306-0):5)
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to write to (the path in) the database: `setValue at /Users/Lenders/5mfvkS1vGndftKXzsE4yUkt4TMC2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`. I recommend searching for such error messages going forward, as this has come up a few times before already.

Comment: I figured this out. I wrote the permissions in firebase with the word "true" in double quotes so it was looking at as a string and not an actual value

Comment: Good to hear you got it work Timothy 